# Reload gridview with different data after onitemclick

Tags: android, android-activity, android-gridview

I've an activity with a gridview. I can fill this layout and set a listener for every items of grid. Now I would reload same gridview with different data after click on one items. Is possible?

Comment: after clicking items simply clear gridview,  get another data and set it to gridview.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set listener to a GridView and once a lick has happened change you data and then refresh the Grid.

Have a look at this:

```
final GridView grid = new GridView(this); // Could be findViewById(R.id.grid) 
        grid.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.id.text1)); // Use your own Adapter with real data
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
            {
                //Do something - change the data of the List/Array/etc

                // Now you can try this:
                ((ArrayAdapter<String>)grid.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

                // Or this:
                grid.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this, android.R.id.text1));

            }
        });
```

Comment: No. Its the same GridView... only the Adapter changes

Comment: @Givi Thank you soo much, it works, you save my day, i been working on that from 2 days, Thanks.